# search key value pair in multi-dimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Thank you very much for reading!

I have a JSON object I need to search through to find if a value is there. The issue I am having is looking into an array, then inside the Feature array, to test if "In Ground Pool" exists.

Thank you!

targetListing is my JSON object

```
var targetFeature = "In Ground Pool";

function valuateFeature(targetFeature){
    for( var i = 0, len = targetListing.Features.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        if( targetListing.Features[i][0] === targetFeature ) {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    };

} ;
```

```js
Address
:
Object
AgentEmail
:
"xxxxx"
AgentId
:
"xxxx"
AgentName
:
"Richard Getz"
AgentPhone
:
"xxxx"
AllListings
:
false
Bath
:
0
Bedroom
:
5
Brokerage
:
"xxxx"
BuildingStyle
:
"House"
BuildingStyleId
:
1
DaysPosted
:
0
Description
:
"If you've ever ..."
Features
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
Description
:
"In Ground Pool"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
Description
:
"Attached Garage"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]
HouseType
:
"Mediterranean"
HouseTypeId
:
3
Images
:
Array[0]
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the JSON (use jsonlint.com to format it nicely). It's impossible to tell the structure of the data from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `lodash.filter`

```
var foundListings = _.filter(targetListing.Features, function() {
   return this[0] === targetFeature
}

var found = foundListings.length > 0;
```

Something like that.  There's several lodash functions that could be appropriate.  `find` perhaps

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#filter

Comment: Native javascript arrays already have a widely supported filter method.

Answer (score 0):

I found it :)

I needed to target inside the array properly.

```
targetListing.Features[0]["Description"]
```